# Turn string text around

Tags: batch-file

Sorry for pure question and showing no effort, but I am completely lost here. I need to make a script that will take a certain variable and turn the string backwards. For example:

> input: "Today is a good day"
>
> output: "yad doog a si yadoT"

I would appreciate anything that would help me do this. I'm completely lost and don't even know where to start. I just started learning batch and it's probably one of the toughest languages that I've ever learned. Thank you!

Comment: I need it purely for learning purposes. I already know many other languages (some basics for python, c#, c++, delphi and java) but this one just takes the complete bottom, I've never had so much trouble learning a new language. I know the function will be pretty useless at the end but I would still appreciate a solution

Comment: why learn batch in the first place? Use it to do simple one off task. Anything other than that use a programming language or even powershell/vbscript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
@echo off
set line=%~1
set num=0

:LOOP
  call set tmpa=%%line:~%num%,1%%%
  set /a num+=1
  if not "%tmpa%" equ "" (
    set rline=%tmpa%%rline%
    goto LOOP
  )

echo %rline%
set rline=
```

Usage:

```
C:\>test.bat "Today is a good day"
yad doog a si yadoT
```

*Note:* Batch requires quotes when passing in arguments with spaces.